# Efficient way of insert millions of rows, convert data and deal with it, on PostgreSQL+PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, optimization, loading, postgis

I have a big collection of data I want to use for user search later.
Currently I have 200 millions resources (~50GB). For each, I have latitude+longitude. The goal is to create spatial index to be able to do spatial queries on it.
So for that, the plan is to use PostgreSQL + PostGIS.

My data are on CSV file. I tried to use custom function to not insert duplicates, but after days of processing I gave up. I found a way to load it fast in the database: with COPY it takes less than 2 hours.

Then, I need to convert latitude+longitude on Geometry format. For that I just need to do:

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longi::double precision,lat::double precision),4326))
```

After some checking, I saw that for 200 millions, I have 50 millions points. So, I think the best way is to have a table "TABLE_POINTS" that will store all the points, and a table "TABLE_RESOURCES" that will store resources with point_key.

So I need to fill "TABLE_POINTS" and "TABLE_RESOURCES" from temporary table "TABLE_TEMP" and not keeping duplicates.

For "POINTS" I did:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_POINTS (point)
SELECT DISTINCT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longi::double precision,lat::double precision),4326))
FROM TABLE_RESOURCES
```

I don't remember how much time it took, but I think it was matter of hours.

Then, to fill "RESOURCES", I tried:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_RESOURCES (...,point_key)
SELECT DISTINCT ...,point_key
FROM TABLE_TEMP, TABLE_POINTS
WHERE ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longi::double precision,lat::double precision),4326) = point;
```

but again take days, and there is no way to see how far the query is ...

Also something important, the number of resources will continue to grow up, currently should be like 100K added by day, so storage should be optimized to keep fast access to data.

So if you have any idea for the loading or the optimization of the storage you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into optimizing postgres first (ie google postgres unlogged, wal and fsync options), second do you really need points to be unique? Maybe just have one table with resources and points combined and not worry about duplicate points as it seems your duplicate lookup maybe whats slow.

Answer (score 0):

For `DISTINCT` to work efficiently, you'll need a database index on those columns for which you want to eliminate duplicates (e.g. on the latitude/longitude columns, or even on the set of all columns).

So first insert all data into your temp table, then `CREATE INDEX` (this is usually faster that creating the index beforehand, as maintaining it during insertion is costly), and only afterwards do the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT DISTINCT`.

An `EXPLAIN <your query>` can tell you whether the `SELECT DISTINCT` now uses the index.